# fluentd twitter plugin occur the error 'access_token' parameter is required even I write it

Tags: twitter, fluentd

I have a problem with fluentd twitter plugin. It tells me `'access_token' parameter is required` but I gave it access_token already.

here is my `/etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf` (I regenerated keys and secrets so It's okay showing it.)

```
<source>
  @type twitter
  consumer_key        CmHQ2sJOoqtkp3ePdqrBySQQ6
  consumer_secret     SoUzVvNe6BjzNH554qTupK849Wgsub31wMRtDBGF1M1Ldh9HiY
  oauth_token         1351694296613679104-2PEN0LoOzeDN1qlxS2p3IPBchEQDah
  oauth_token_secret  oNqwr57MU5TGb21P1MEU4GfgcITDOs1LmgN5tYiPlfHcG
  tag                 input.twitter.sampling
  timeline            sampling
  keyword             game
  output_format       nest
</source>
<match input.twitter>
  @type stdout
</match>
```

and here is the log when I execute `td-agent`

```
~$ td-agent
2021-01-20 07:13:09 +0000 [info]: parsing config file is succeeded path="/etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf"
2021-01-20 07:13:09 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-elasticsearch' version '4.1.1'
2021-01-20 07:13:09 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-kafka' version '0.14.1'
2021-01-20 07:13:09 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-prometheus' version '1.8.2'
2021-01-20 07:13:09 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-prometheus_pushgateway' version '0.0.2'
2021-01-20 07:13:09 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-record-modifier' version '2.1.0'
2021-01-20 07:13:09 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-rewrite-tag-filter' version '2.3.0'
2021-01-20 07:13:09 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-s3' version '1.4.0'
2021-01-20 07:13:09 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-systemd' version '1.0.2'
2021-01-20 07:13:09 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-td' version '1.1.0'
2021-01-20 07:13:09 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-twitter' version '0.6.1'
2021-01-20 07:13:09 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-webhdfs' version '1.2.5'
2021-01-20 07:13:09 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluentd' version '1.11.2'
2021-01-20 07:13:09 +0000 [error]: config error in:
<source>
  @type twitter
  consumer_key xxxxxx
  consumer_secret xxxxxx
  oauth_token 1351694296613679104-2PEN0LoOzeDN1qlxS2p3IPBchEQDah
  oauth_token_secret oNqwr57MU5TGb21P1MEU4GfgcITDOs1LmgN5tYiPlfHcG
  tag "input.twitter.sampling"
  timeline sampling
  keyword "game"
  output_format nest
</source>

2021-01-20 07:13:09 +0000 [error]: config error file="/etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf" error_class=Fluent::ConfigError error="'access_token' parameter is required"
```

Comment: Is this because you've called the token `oauth_token` in the conf file, but it is looking for `access_token`?

Comment: @AndyPiper no, i check official document several times. there is no option like `access_token`